# MVC OutputCache with button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my Controller, which is decorated with OutputCache attribute, as following:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "version", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
    public ActionResult ListModules(int version)
```

The caching works fine when the action is called using Html.ActionLink.

However, I also call this page from a button click of another page. The button functionality is handled in javascript, and then there is a call to the action as:

```
window.location = "../Module/ListModules?version=" + version;
```

Now when page is called this way, the cached page is not used, and the action is called again. Is there a way to use the cached page on redirection using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: are you changing the version the URL from the previous call?

Comment: No its the same version

Comment: Is the `version` param changing from request to request. Your `OutputCache` config includes `VaryByParam="version"` so it will check the version and serve a fresh page if it changes. Try using the Chrome inspector to see the exact request that is being made. It may give you a clue as to why there is an issue.